# "Forbid" user to enter 2 characters

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my first question here, I hope I'll be specific enough..

The thing is, I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe game in C++ and I'm having some problems with it..

The setup is like this:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Enter X Position: // user input - a number from 1-9

It's a two dimensional **char** array (the reason for it being char is because I will eventually need to replace all of the characters with X or O).

I can make it work, that is... when I ask either player X or player O to enter a number for their position, it turns into an X or an O.
I have an if statement that presents users with an error if they enter anything other than numbers from 1-9, and it works.. except for a tiny problem:

If player X enters, for example, "23", both 2 and 3 in my array turn into an X which should not happen:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Enter X Position: 23

---

1 X 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

---

1 X X

4 5 6

7 8 9

Is there any way I can make a two-or-more-character-input go into my error-if-statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve], without any code we can only guess at what issues you might be having.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, well here questions which don't show any effort are not well received.. it'd be good if you include code of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you want using std::getline

Documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

With that you can check if the length of the returned string is larger than 1 to go into your error if-else.

To then change that as a number you can use atoi after doing some verification that it is an actual number.
(In pure c++ you could use stringstream to convert to a number http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

Answer (score 0):

You said, you have a two dimensional char array. 
I would make a simple one dimensional char array with 9 fields (from 0-8). 
When you ask a player for a position(1-9) you let them enter an int value and set the array field with the number-1 to the according Symbol.

something like:

```
    char arr[9];
    //set all positions to numbers
    int i=10;
    std::cout<<"Player X, enter position!" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    i=i-1;
    if(i<0 || i>8) {
    //error
    }
    arr[i]='x';
```

Comment: and for printing the array you just print the first 3 values, then an endl, then three again, a endl and then the last ones.

Comment: I know that works as well, but mine works fine too.. the problem I have is when the user inputs two numbers, e.g. "45" or "78", both numbers transform into either an O or an X, but I want the program to present the user with an error message.